# FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}

Tags: ansible

Im trying to get the IP address and hostname of worker nodes and writing it on master /root/hosts file .Getting error, FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}

```
- name: set glusterfs device in hostfile
  shell: echo "{{ name }} glusterfs_devices='[ \"/dev/abcd\" ]'"
  register: opt_gluster
  when: type == "worker"

- name: add glusterfs
  lineinfile:
    dest: /root/hosts
    line: "{{item}}"
    insertafter: EOF
  with_items:
       - "{{ opt_gluster.stdout }}"
  when: type == "master"
```

```
{"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
```

Comment: Consider doing this as a fact instead of a return from a task.

Comment: can you please share an example .. that would be helpful.

Comment: I updated my code ... so I have to gather IP address and hostname of workers and write it on master so how I use the condition if I use fact instead of task?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the when statment of

```
- name: add glusterfs
  lineinfile:
    dest: /root/hosts
    line: "{{item}}"
    insertafter: EOF
  with_items:
       - "{{ opt_gluster.stdout }}"
  when: type == "master"
```

I think it's missing a

```
when: type == "master" and opt_gluster.stdout is defined
```

Because when you are on a node who won't be a `worker` opt_gluster won't have a stdout because it's skipping.

Best Regards

Comment: Now its not throwing an error but skipping the master node for the task ie it is not inserting line in file

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure of what you need exactly, could you post a result of your ansible-playbook command ? I don't understand exactly how `type` could be worker and master at same time.

Comment: ```type``` is different for the two tasks.First task I'm running on the nodes whose type are worker ( defined in inventory file) and in second task I want to write the output of first task (ran on worker nodes) to master node /root/hosts location

Comment: The above code was my approach if you have any idea how to achieve that scenario I would really appreciate it